# recognize spacial number in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to Write a function that get a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 . see some result for example .

`spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
 spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
 spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False`

I have a code for it and it's work ( see below )
but I want another solution!

```
def spy_game(nums):

    code = [0,0,7,'x']

    for num in nums:
        if num == code[0]:
            code.pop(0)   # code.remove(num) also works

    return len(code) == 1
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Why not write that function?

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: code for detect 0,0,7 in a list for example [1,0,2,4,0,5,7]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework problem, so rather than giving an outright solution I'll offer a way of considering the problem instead.

Both strings and lists in Python are iterable types, so you can apply a solution for this that exists for strings (namely, [`.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)) and apply it on the list instead.

A helpful function on strings is also the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method, which creates a string out of a list.

So one way you could look if the list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` contains the sequence `s = ['d', 'e', 'f']` is to turn both into strings and check if `''.join(s) in ''.join(l)`. For your example, since the elements of the lists are not strings, you will have to convert them to make them work with `.join()`.

I suspect there's also a solution buried in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) package, but it would probably be overkill here.